# python code slow skin detection

Tags: python

This code changes the color space to LAB and using a threshold finds the skin area of an image. but it's ridiculously slow. I don't know how to make it faster ?

```
from colormath.color_objects import *

def skinDetection(img, treshold=80, color=[255,20,147]):

    print img.shape
    res=img.copy()
    for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            RGBimg=RGBColor(img[x,y,0],img[x,y,1],img[x,y,2])
            LABimg=RGBimg.convert_to('lab', debug=False)
            if (LABimg.lab_l > treshold):
                res[x,y,:]=color
            else: 
                res[x,y,:]=img[x,y,:]

    return res
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested loops are always slow in Python. You iterate over each Pixel, thus it takes a lot of time.

It's always faster to do vectorized operations, i.e., perform operations on arrays as a whole and let the underlying C-routines do the looping.

I do not know `colormath` well, and thus I cannot provide the corresponding code for this library (and don't know if it exists), but for `scikit-image`, I can:

```
def mask2(rgb, threshold=80, color=[255,20,147]):
    res = rgb.copy()
    lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(rgb)
    mask = lab[:,:,0] > threshold
    res[mask] = np.array(color).reshape(1,-1).repeat(mask.sum(),axis=0)
    return res
```

I convert the whole image to LAB-space, then determine a mask (where L is above the threshold) and then set these pixels to a new color. This method produces slightly different results than your method (probably because of different conversion-implementations) but maybe it satisfies your needs.

Below is a complete script, including your method (`mask1`) and performance measurements.

```
from binascii import unhexlify
import zlib
from cStringIO import StringIO
import skimage.io, skimage.color
from colormath.color_objects import RGBColor
import numpy as np


def mask1(img, treshold=80, color=[255,20,147]):
    res=img.copy()
    for x in range(img.shape[0]):
        for y in range(img.shape[1]):
            RGBimg=RGBColor(img[x,y,0],img[x,y,1],img[x,y,2])
            LABimg=RGBimg.convert_to('lab', debug=False)
            if (LABimg.lab_l > treshold):
                res[x,y,:]=color
            else: 
                res[x,y,:]=img[x,y,:]
    return res

def mask2(rgb, threshold=80, color=[255,20,147]):
    res = rgb.copy()
    lab = skimage.color.rgb2lab(rgb)
    mask = lab[:,:,0] > threshold
    res[mask] = np.array(color).reshape(1,-1).repeat(mask.sum(),axis=0)
    return res

sdata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
fh = StringIO(zlib.decompress(unhexlify(sdata)))
rgb = skimage.io.imread(fh)

res1 = mask1(rgb)
res2 = mask2(rgb)

import timeit
t1 = timeit.timeit("mask1(rgb)", setup="from __main__ import rgb, mask1", number=100)
t2 = timeit.timeit("mask2(rgb)", setup="from __main__ import rgb, mask2", number=100)

print t1, t2, t1/t2
```

I embedded an image into this code, and some parts of the code are just for decoding it.

The output of this script is

```
4.43572092984 0.0531735152348 83.4197421453
```

So my method is **80** times as fast as yours. For larger images (this one is only 24 x 24 pixels) the difference is even bigger, something like 120 times as fast.

### Behold the power of vectorization!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to follow a simple process to optimize your code :
1. Add some performance metrics. You have to learn which part of your code is taking to most of the time.
2. Update theses functions by more performing ones
3. Measure the performance improvements